# Convert Word Table to HTML in Memory

Tags: html, ms-word

Because of Word's odd managing of merge cells, it's very difficult to determine merged cells in Word (technically, there is no merged property on a cell, it's only a method, so we have to "guess" as to what is merged).

Although not perfect, I've discovered one way to help in determining merge cells. If you save a `.docx` file as a `filtered html file` (.htm), you can then look at the mark-up in the .htm file and look at the `colspan` property for each cell.

I want to avoid going the very costly route of first saving the .docx as a .htm (using the Document.SaveAs method), then parsing the .htm to determine the colspan values for each cell.

Is there any I can directly save a table into memory in .htm format and then pull the values from there?

An alternative could be using the algorithm that the conversation uses to determine the colspan, but I haven't found anything on the internet about that, and I want to avoid writing the complex algorithm myself, if possible.

Comment: Wow, that's as much fun as trying to un-boil an egg.

Comment: @Shark. Perhaps you need to modify your question to say what you are trying to achieve more generally.  Are you trying to extract tables from a word document and create a HTML version?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41973014/how-to-identify-merged-column-and-row-in-word-table/42371294#42371294 Perhaps this helps?